# Crash in release mode when loading a plist

Tags: ios, cocoa, swift

I have been loading data from a plist fine in a couple view controllers using this code:

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("eBaySiteIDs", ofType: "plist") {

        if let dict = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as? Array<AnyObject> {
            // use swift dictionary as normal
            countryArray = dict as? [[String : AnyObject]]
        }
    }
```

This runs properly in debug mode, but as soon I build for release mode, the app crashes when trying to access the countryArray, saying it is nil.

Any ideas?

Thanks

**EDIT**

If I try to log the array using

```
NSLog("\(NSArray(contentsOfFile: path))")
```

I get the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that you don't have added your resource to your Build Phase yet. So it may work in debug mode, but in release mode, the file is missing.

So, you have to add the video in your Xcode `target` under `Build Phases` to the `Copy Bundle Resources`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

For some reason I needed to change the statement to:

```
if let dict : AnyObject = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) {

}
```